# Run cypress in Jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, cypress, httpconfiguration

I have this problem since two weeks till now. Kindly advise what to do with an error like HTTP PROXY configuration and no local issuer certificate.

I just wanted to run my cypress test from git repo and automate the execution